# Why isn't the try/catch catching the access violation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

I put a try/catch block around a bit of code that occasionaly throws an expected exception, but rather than catching it and displaying the message box, it stops the debugger and alerts me that the exception is unhandled.

How do I handle this exception so my code doesn't stop when the exception occurs?

[image]

```
Friend myDevInfo As New devInfo

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Closes the device handle obtained with CreateFile and frees resources.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' 
        Friend Sub CloseDeviceHandle()

            Try
                WinUsb_Free(myDevInfo.winUsbHandle)

                If Not (myDevInfo.deviceHandle Is Nothing) Then
                    If Not (myDevInfo.deviceHandle.IsInvalid) Then
                        myDevInfo.deviceHandle.Close()
                    End If
                End If

            Catch ex As System.AccessViolationException
                MsgBox("System.AccessViolationException")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw
            End Try

        End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have the Debug -> Exceptions configured to halt on exceptions?

Comment: I believe the default setting is to break on `AccessViolationException`

Comment: You should not try to catch an `AccessViolationException`. You should fix the bug causing it. This exception should never be expected.

Comment: Just hit F5 and you'll reach the catch block.

Comment: @CodeInChaos That is, generally speaking, true.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek No, when I hit F5 it continues to show the violation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `try...catch` block should work as expected, when no debugger is attached.
You can define what exceptions the debugger breaks on under Debug -> Exceptions, I believe the default is to break on `AccessViolationException`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see that option in `Debug` --> `Options and Settings...` can you give me a clue where to look?

Comment: Also, is there a way to execute the project inside the IDE without invoking the debugger so I can test this out?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio of you using? It should be in `Debug` -> `Exceptions...`, not in `Options and Settings`.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can run it without attaching the debugger using `Debug` -> `Start without Debugging`, or `CTRL+F5` (default shortcut).

Comment: You can change the exceptions that the debugger breaks on by pressing Ctrl + Alt + E

Answer (score 1):

An access violation exception falls into a class of exceptions called 'corrupted state exceptions'.  With .Net 4, Microsoft took the decision that these should no longer be caught by try .. catch blocks.  Their reasoning is that it takes understanding and care to recover from corrupted state exceptions without causing more damage, and that it is safer for users' data, if the application is closed down.

MSDN will tell you [how to reverse this change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use this attribute on the top of the function that you are using.

```
 [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions()]
```

This exception occurs with only unsafe or protected memory. The memory that is not been allocated . If you use this attribute then the clr will detect it and the try-catch block is working fine present in :

```
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
```